# how to extract specific key and value from a dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas

[image: [enter image description here][1][]

I want to extract name(a) and respective scores(90) from a data frame
As you can see here I used iloc method to get the scores of respective names.
The only problem is if names get interchanged in a dataframe we can't get accurate scores.
Can we extract name as key and score as a value using python?
By this way we can avoid hardcoding.

Code :

```
name_dict = {
    'Name': ['a','b','c','d'],
    'Score': [90,80,95,20]}
df = pd.DataFrame(name_dict)

print (df)

df.iloc[0,1]
```

Output :

```
90
```

Comment: Do you want to use `Name` as index?

Comment: yes call name: a and get output as score:90 and store it into a variable

Comment: then `df.set_index('Name').loc['a', 'Score']`

Comment: Hi @AK007 I have provided an answer to your question, let me know if you need any more help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the index of the dataframe to the `Name` column

```
df.set_index('Name', inplace=True)
```

Then you can fetch the score as

```
df.loc['a', 'Score']
```